# IONIC2 firebase facebook auth reauthentication

Tags: ionic2, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

How to enable facebook reauthentication for an ionic2 app, which is authenticating firebase too? 
Can facebook reauthentication be done without changing the UID of the user?

Comment: Vague question.. start with this https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/facebook-login ?

Comment: I don't see it as a vague question. You authenticate once, then you want to use something like native storage to save the credentials to reauthenticate. It doesn't seem to work so well and isn't mentioned on your link, Facebook does contain information about this and it doesn't seem to be able to be leveraged in Firebase. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/reauthentication/